# Create a reference to a Cloud Storage document in Firestore

Tags: firebase, reference, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase, and I try to create a reference to a Cloud Storage document in a Firestore document.

In my Console > Storage, I have a folder `discovery` that contains a file `heart.png`.

In my Firestore document, I have a `reference` field named `src`. I have tried to fill it with:

- `discovery/heart.png`
- `gs://<NAME>.appspot.com/discovery/heart.png`
- `<NAME>.appspot.com/discovery/heart.png`

but it doesn't work...
When I try to get the image like this `src.get().then(snap => console.log(snap.data()))` the result is always `undefined`.

Does the reference fields are only designed for the database's documents (not Storage ones)?
I can't find how to reference a Storage file in a Firestore document neither on the documentation nor on Google.

Could someone help me, please? :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Answer on one of your questions below. If you're having trouble reading/writing a Cloud Storage URL to Firestore with that knowledge, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `Reference` field type of Cloud Firestore can only refer to another document in the Firestore database.

If you want to refer to an object/location in Cloud Storage, you'll have to store that as a compatible type. For example by storing the download URL of the object, or the path to the object.